# Code keeps different variables under the same name instead of overwriting

Tags: c, recursion

I'm pretty much a beginner, and while I was learning about recursion, I came across this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void reverseSentence();

int main()
{
    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    reverseSentence();

    return 0;
}

void reverseSentence()
{
    char letter;
    scanf("%c", &letter);

    if( letter != '\n')
    {
        reverseSentence();
        printf("%c",letter);
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is, isn't it supposed to change the letter variable every time the function is called? I thought it wouldn't work because of that but somehow reverses a sentence like it's supposed to.

Comment: The `letter` variable is declared inside the function (and not `static`), so it's a new variable for each call of the function.

Comment: @Paul Hankin So, does the computer tell the `letter` variables apart by which call of the function they were defined in?

Answer (score 2):

This is related to duration and scoping. Here `letter` is declared in a block  (in fact in a function) and is not static. It is said to be an *automatic* variable. Each and every invocation of the function will get its own version of the variable and will be independant of the one in any other invocation. That is the reason why the code produces the expected result.

What you imagine would be a static duration variable:

```
static char letter;
```

A static variable get its address at program startup and its value will be shared among any invocation of the function (or block) where it is declared.

In common implementations, static variables have a fixed address in the global variables segment, while automatic ones live in the stack, which explains how recursive invocations of a function can have different values for the variable.